# what makes xmpp a trustworthy way to communicate with others?

Tags: encryption, xmpp

- [An Overview of XMPP](https://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview.html)
- [Luke Smith recommends XMPP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBTsUVrCD)

As Luke Smith said in his video, XMPP has been designed as an open communication protocol, which is similar to the email at an extent, I am wondering why people consider it as a safe communication method. So far as I know, the XMPP protocol itself doesn't provide any encryption to ensure the visibility of messages to only the sender and receiver. So, how does XMPP protocol protection work?

Answer (score 1):

**It isn't.**

XMPP Chat is a federated protocol just like email.

- It may or may not use TLS client to server, but generally does these
  days.
- The federated servers hold and relay clear text chat just like email.
- End-to-End encryption is dependent upon client side body encryption
  just like email.